# Como verificar se um produto já foi comprado pelo usuário no iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Galera, quando eu quero validar se um produto do meu aplicativo (um InApp) já foi adquirido pelo usuário, no Windows Phone basta eu verificar o produto através do LicenceInformation. Por exemplo:

```
var license = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["id_do_meu_produto"];
if (!license.IsActive) 
{
  // O usuário ainda não comprou este item
  ...
}
```

Agora a dúvida: Tem como fazer isso no iOS? Um amigo que tem um aplicativo publicado na Apple Store diz que não tem jeito sem primeiro obrigar o usuário a se logar na loja.

Como fazer para verificar se o usuário já pagou por um item?

Infelizmente alguns usuários (poucos) estão comprando o produto e depois pedindo o extorno para a Apple. Assim, eles ficam com o produto de graça.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta assim:

```
- (void) verificaItensComprados {
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}//chame essa funçao

//no delegate da funcao
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
  itensCompradosIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"numero de produtos a ser restabelecido: %i", queue.transactions.count);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
  {
      NSString *produtoID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
      [itensCompradosIDs addObject:produtoID];
  }
}
```

Comment: Vlw William vou testar e falo o resultado.

Comment: avisa se der certo =D

Comment: Fala William. Deu certo, mas pediu autenticação do usuario antes. Tem algum jeito de verificar a compra do produto sem que seja solicitado que o usuario faça o login antes? Como no Windows Phone não é possivel ter mais de um usuario, acho que deve ser por isso que não pede autenticação.

Comment: acredito que não pois a compra e vinculada ao usuário.

Comment: Blz William. Vlw pela força. Vou continuar pesquisando e se achar algo posto aqui. Abraços.